# show in different lines

Tags: python-2.7, recursion

I want to show the answers in different lines

```
def f(k,e) :
    if e==0 :
        return '*'
    return k*' '+'*'+e*' '+'*'+ f(k,e-1)
```

result:

```
*            *
 *          *
  *        *
   *      *
    *    *
     *  *
      *
```

Answer (score 0):

To add line breaks, you can simply use `\n`. However, the code above still won't create the ASCII "V" as indicated.

Here's an example that may be closer to what you're attempting:

```
#create an ASCII 'V' with the indicated character and number of lines
def buildV(lineCount, char):
    lines = []
    currentLine = 1
    while currentLine <= lineCount:
        indent = currentLine * ' '
        if currentLine < lineCount:
            gap = ((lineCount - currentLine) * 2 - 1) * ' '
            lines.append(indent + char + gap + char)
        else:
            lines.append(indent + char)
        currentLine += 1
    return '\n'.join(lines)

#examples
print(buildV(9, 'V'))
print(buildV(6, '#'))
print(buildV(2, '*'))
```

Output:

```
 V               V
  V             V
   V           V
    V         V
     V       V
      V     V
       V   V
        V V
         V
 #         #
  #       #
   #     #
    #   #
     # #
      #
 * *
  *
```

Comment: but I need to use the recursion and '\n' don't work!